# PHP form gets submitted but the data is blank

Tags: php, html

My html code looks like this, also included is the php file. The form gets submitted and the data headings like "Name :", "Email :", etc. is there but required data is blank.

Please see the example below:

```
Name:
Phone:
E-Mail:
Message:
```

Can someone explain, what's wrong with my code?

```html
<form id="zpro-contact-form" action="mailer.php" method="POST">

  <div class="box_sec3">
    <div class="three_box2">
      <p class="text3">Name</p>
      <div class="form_box">
        <input class="input-field form" name="name" type="text" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three_box2">
      <div class="form_box">
        <p class="text3">Phone</p>
        <input class="tel-number-field long form" name="phone" type="text" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three_box2">
      <div class="form_box">
        <p class="text3">Email</p>
        <input class="input-field form" name="email" type="email" required="">
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="box_sec4">
    <p class="text3">Message</p>
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field form2" required=""></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="wapper">
    <label>
      <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="SUBMIT" class="send" /> 
    </label>
    <p class="zpro-send-message"></p>
</form>
```

Here is the mailer.php I have tried replacing variable "REQUEST" with "POST" but its still coming back blank.

```
   <?php
        //print_r($_FILES);
        //include("dbconnection.php");
        //include("header.php");
        //include('st.html');
        //include('contact.php');
        //print_r($_POST);
        //session_start();

    ?>
    <?php 
         $to = "....@......";
         $subject = "Inquiry from website" ;
         $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ; 

         $message .= " Name: ".$_REQUEST['name'] ; 
         $message .= "\n Phone: ".$_REQUEST['phone'] ; 
         $message .= "\n E-Mail: ".$_REQUEST['email'] ; 
         $message .= "\n Message: ".$_REQUEST['message'] ; 
         $headers = "From: $email";
         $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
         $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
         $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) ; 

         if($sent) 
         {
             echo "<script>window.location='/thank_you.html'</script>";
         }
         else 
         {
             echo "<script>window.location='/thank_you.html'</script>";
         }
     ?>
```

Comment: what does print_r($_POST); produce ?

Comment: Have you tried $_POST['name'] instead  of $_REQUEST['name']?

Comment: @JayMillena - unless there's something really weird in the ini config, that should make no difference whatsoever.

Comment: add error_reporting("E_ALL"); at the top of mailer.php and check if any errors exists.

Comment: Also why not `if($sent) { header("location: thankyou.html"); }`

Comment: `echo "<script>window.location='/thank_you.html'</script>";` ... it would be *far* better to use `header()` for that, that way nothing is output to the screen and the browser won't cache the page.

Comment: you have undefined variable $message and you are trying to concatenate it. define $message = ""; just above using it.

Comment: Is it upset because you set the mail type as "text/HTML" but put plain text in the message body?

Comment: @droopsnoot that should not be it, I think; for one, plain text inside HTML is not much of a problem in general (provided it contains no HTML “special characters”), plus it would not explain why they see their “labels” here but not the actual values behind them.

Comment: What HTTP response you get from the server?

Comment: Assuming you are using Chrome, can you check in the NETWORK tab, if the values get indeed send?

Comment: Typo in the second `$headers` line means that there is no from-address being set. Seems strange that it will send without one, but maybe the configuration has a default.

Comment: @SandeepModak adding error_reporting("E_ALL"); is showing no error. Form is submitting but with blank data

Comment: @mplungjan adding header location shows internal server error

Comment: @droopsnoot typo corrected. Doesn't make much difference

Comment: The you have other headers or are outputting something before

Comment: The form was working fine till about a couple of months ago. I don't know what changed after that.

Comment: i checked your code at my end it shows undefined variable $message . have you tried defining it just above using the same .Add your form also in your query ?